# Unexpected results of integer/double interaction - zero is returned after the division operation

Tags: java, variables, methods

I have an issue with the "documentLength" variable.
When i input the paramenter into the method, it is 93. But for some reason it changes. The input parameter is also an int variable.

I call the class Word, and the method inside it occupationOfDocument from the class checkWord in main like this:

```
double occupation = word.get(1).occupationOfDocument(documentLength); // line 83 in run-time below
```

occupationOfDocument looks like this

```
public double occupationOfDocument(int documentLength){
    int length = getLength(); //equals 8 when I run the program
    int occurances = getOccurances(); //equals 3 when I run the program
    System.out.println(documentLength); //Prints 93 as expected

    double occupation = ((length * occurances)/documentLength)*100; //equals 0 somehow (probably division by)

    return occupation; //expected around 25.8
}
```

This method returns "0", but if I change the code to this,

```
private int documentLength = 0;
public double occupationOfDocument(int documentLength){
    int length = getLength(); //equals 8 when I run the program
    int occurances = getOccurances(); //equals 3 when I run the program
    documentLength = this.documentLength;
    System.out.println(documentLength); //Prints 0 somehow

    double occupation = ((length * occurances)/documentLength)*100; //equals 0 somehow (probably divisjon by 0)

    return occupation; //expected around 25.8
}
```

I get the following RUN-TIME-error:

> ```
> Exception in thread "main" java.lang.ArithmeticException: / by zero
>     at Word.occupationOfDocument(Word.java:44)
>     at checkWord.main(checkWord.java:83)
> ```

Word.java:44 
    This is the line with math, where i declare and initialize occupation

I understand that it says I am dividing by 0. I just don't understand how it happens.

If i input a number instead of the variable "documentLength", the script does as expected

Thanks for helping ;)

IT student in need of help

Comment: First, you should do `this.documentLength = documentLength`, not the other way around. This fixes your `0` issue. Second, you're dividing using two `int`s, so you should cast one of them to `double` or your result will probably be `0`.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
public double occupationOfDocument(int documentLength){
  int length = getLength(); //equals 8 when I run the program
  int occurances = getOccurances(); //equals 3 when I run the program
  System.out.println(documentLength); //Prints 93 as expected

  double occupation = ((length * occurances)/documentLength)*100; //equals 0 somehow (probably division by)

  return occupation; //expected around 25.8
```

}

Here, you have multiplied 8 by 3 and gotten 24, then you did **integer** division by 93 - and that gives you 0.

If you modify the line

```
double occupation = ((double) (length * occurances)/documentLength)*100;
```

that will produce the appropriate result. Learn more about [type conversion and type widening](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se7/html/jls-5.html) to get more context.

Answer (score 0):

You are doing integer division in the first scenario, that means for example `4/3 = 1` and in your case `24/93 = 0` if you want to get it as a double you need to add a cast to the int values:

`double occupation = (((double)(length * occurances))/((double)documentLength))*100;`

Should be safe. As for the second error you explicitly tell the program to

`documentLength = this.documentLength; //this.documentLength = 0 as you defined above`

`double occupation = ((length * occurances)/documentLength)*100;`